# Vanishing locus of a general section of a vector bundle.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $\geq 2$ and $E$ a vector bundle on $X$ of rank $r\geq 2$. Is it true that, if $E$ is globally generated, then the zero locus of a general section of $E$ has codimension $\geq r$ in $X$?

Comment: Quick correction: You want $r$ to be the rank of $E$, not the dimension of $X$. 

Comment: sorry! Of course you are right!

Comment: If $E$ is trivial, this isn't true because the zero sets are empty for
general sections. You need to make $E$ "sufficiently positive". Precise criteria can probably found in Lazarsfeld's book on positivity.


Comment: Actually I am interested in knowing whether the codimension of the zero locus is at least $r$. I was imprecise when formulating the question.

Comment: I think this is Lemma 5.2 in "3264 and All That".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Donu pointed out, it may happen that the general section has no zeroes.  Anyway, the  the answer to your question is *yes*.

This is a special case of the following more general result "of Bertini type" about degeneracy loci of morphism of vector bundles, whose proof can be found in Ottaviani's book *Varietà proiettive di codimensione piccola*. This book is in italian; if you prefer a treatment in english, look at Lazarsfeld's book *Positivity in algebraic geometry II*, Section 7.2, and at the references given therein.

> **Theorem.** Let $\phi \colon F \to E$ be a morphism between vector bundles on $X$, with $\textrm{rank} \, F=s$, $\textrm{rank} \, E=r$,  and let $D_k(\phi)$ be the set of points $x \in X$ such that $\phi_x \colon F_x \to E_x$ has rank $\leq k$.
>
> If $F^{*} \otimes E$ is generated by global sections, then for the general $\phi$ either $D_k(\phi)$ is empty or it has the expected codimension $(s-k)(r-k)$.
>
> Moreover, if $F^{*} \otimes E$ is ample and  $(s-k)(r-k) < \dim X$, then for the general $\phi$ the locus $D_k(\phi)$ is non-empty, of the expected codimension $(s-k)(r-k)$.

Now apply this result to the morphism $$\phi \colon \mathcal{O}_X \to E$$
induced by the section. Since $D_0(\phi)$ is exactly the locus where the section vanishes, you are done.

Comment: If a section has no zeros then the codimension of its zero locus is in fact $\ge r$...

Comment: You are right, but the question was edited. Ok, I can edit the answer too...

Comment: Could you give an English reference for this result? I have hard time finding this book.